# How to colorize a specific point with `ListPointPlot3D`

Tags: color

I just want to add a point (x,y,z) with a specific color using `ListPointPlot3D`.

My code:

```
ListPointPlot3D[p13, ImageSize -> Large, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Show[
ListPointPlot3D[p13, ImageSize -> Large, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
,ListPointPlot3D[{x,y,z}, PlotStyle -> specificColor]
]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the data value with `Style` directly.

Start with some random data,

```
SeedRandom[42];
data = RandomReal[40, {20, 3}];
```

Here I wrap the 4th element with `Style`,

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 MapAt[Style[#, Green] &, data, 4]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: @kglr - that sounds like a question of having the cake vs eating the cake.  [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174919/9490) is probably the way to go if you want to have most points colored automatically except for one.